# Good lua code in .tex doesn't work in .sty?

Tags: packages, luatex, luacode

I have some `luacode` in a `.tex` file that works fines, but does't in a `.sty` file -- with this error message :

> Runaway argument?
>   ! File ended while scanning use of \luacode@grab@lines.
>     \par <*> mwe.tex

#### `.tex` file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,mwe}

\begin{document}
% works fine
for i = 0,10
do
    tex.print (i)
end

% doesn't work
\For
\end{document}
```

#### `mwe.sty` file

```
\newcommand{\For}{%
\begin{luacode}
for i = 0,10
do
    tex.print (i)
end
\end{luacode}
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `luacode` environment works by changing catcode codes to make in the input easier to pass to Lua. That can't work inside a macro: the input is already tokenized. In that sense `luacode` is similar to a verbatim environment. For any long block of Lua code you are best having it in a separate file, whilst for short blocks I'd stick to `\directlua` and be aware of the requirements, which here are minimal

```
\newcommand*\For{%
\directlua{
    for i = 0,10 do
      tex.print(i)
    end
  }%
}
```

(You actually get the error as the `\end{luacode}` is being found using a verbatim-like approach, and that will always fail inside a macro.)

Comment: I always do that, having a separate lua code file... Why I thaught a just for moment that `luacode` was cool ;-)

Comment: @Tarass `luacode` does have it's uses, but as it's non-expandable and verbatim-like I tend to think that it's easier to understand the slightly tricky requirements of using `\directlua`.

Comment: @Tarass - The principal advantage of using a `luacode` environment is that the `%` character doesn't have to be escaped to hide it from TeX's eyes. (The `%` character is "special" in Lua, but in a very different way than in TeX.) Since your code example doesn't contain `%` characters, I see no benefit to using a `luacode` environment. As Joseph recommends, use `\luadirect{...}` instead.